# Bootstrap 3 panel mobile scrolling/responsiveness

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my problem: I'm trying to implement a bootstrap 3 panel with a list of users inside. This list is inside another bootstrap 3 panel.
See here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/gwnyyvaa/

```
ok some apparently some code is needed here
```

Now the problem is that on mobile, it does not allow scrolling. I expected it to allow scrolling, since the mobile screen is way to small to display it on one page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap doesn't automatically make panels scroll if there is too much text to display in the panel. So you should add some CSS to do that yourself. Here is the CSS you need to add:

```
.users_list .panel-body {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

This will cause the `.panel-body` of `.user_list` to scroll horizontally if the text would overflow the container.

Here is a fiddle with the above CSS added:
https://jsfiddle.net/89cpmctt/1/

If you want it to scroll vertically, then you would have to assign a height to the panel. This is because divs will expand vertically to fit the content. So you need to add a `height` property to the `.panel-body`. Along with a `overflow-y:auto`. Here is an example

```
.panel-body {
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: I've added the code, and the panel scrolls good. However only the panel inside the parent panel. The actual panel, that contains everything, still does not scroll. I will be trying to get it to scroll using this overflow property. Have you got any idea what the problem could be? Thanks for helping out!

Comment: I just noticed you said horizontally. I meant to scroll vertically. It still does not work, even if i change it to overflow-y. Here is my problem specifically: 1 image, showing the full panel: http://pasteboard.co/xAhW0DMbN.png 2 image: http://pasteboard.co/xAhibEmT6.png showing it resized. The scroll bar shows, but it isnt scrollable down until the button, as shown in image 1

Comment: @BusinessGuy If you want it to scroll, then you would have to add a `height` property to the `.panel-body` in your CSS code. Along with the `overflow-y:auto` of course.